# External Functions Accessing Variables from Parent Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a block of code that looks something like this:

```
const $ = prototype;

(function($){

    myFunc();

})(jQuery)

const myFunc = function () {

    console.log($);

}
```

In this situation the output is going to be `prototype`.  But I want any child functions to have `$` as jQuery.  Bear in mind that the functions have many children.

I could pass `$` as a parameter, or I could define a new local const in each child function.  Is there any way that I can avoid this and make `$ = jQuery` available to all child functions?

Comment: You're trying to circumvent the fundamental scope rules of ECMAScript. Consider working with the language rather than against it, e.g. don't try to use a global *$* constant with two different values. Having two different *myFunc* functions is bad enough (or maybe you meant *myFunc0* and *myFunc1* rather than two functions with the same name).

Comment: alas, if only I had that choice :-(  I only declared one function though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for something like this

```
    var previous = null;
var current = null;

const myFunc = function () {

  console.log($);
  console.log(this.v)
  childfunc()

}
const childfunc = function(){
  var $=this.v
  console.log($)     
  childofchild()
}
const childofchild = function(){
  var $=this.v
  console.log($)
}

const $ = 'prototype';

(function($){
  v=$
    myFunc();

})('jQuery');
```

Comment: Problem is that I want to access via `$` and not `this.$` - But this might end up being the best option.

Comment: I have updated my answer it is a work around because in this scenario you can't assign same constant with 2 different values